# inverse matrix search algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

For ex,

$$A^{-1}\cdot A=\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3 & x_4\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

and

$$A\cdot A^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3 & x_4\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

so we can make two systems:

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   x_1 + 2x_3 = 1, 
   \\
  x_2 + 2x_4 = 0,
   \\
  x_1 + 3 x_3 = 0,
   \\
  x_2 + 3x_4 = 1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   x_1 + x_2 = 1, 
   \\
  2x_1 + 3x_2 = 0,
   \\
  x_3 + x_4 = 0,
   \\
  2 x_3 + 3x_4 = 1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

after line addition we get the system:

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   2x_2 + 5x_4 = 1, 
   \\
  2x_1 + 5x_3 = 1,
   \\
  3 x_1 + 4 x_2 = 1,
   \\
  3 x_3 + 4 x_4 = 1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

We solve the system and find the roots: $(x_1 = -2, x_2 = -2, x_3 = 1, x_4 = 1)$. This is not the inverse matrix. What is obvious. The inverse matrix found by the standard algorithm is equal to

$$A^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix}3 & -2\\-1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

But where are my arguments wrong?

**Edited** correct roots of the last system are:  $x_1 - \frac{10x_4}{3} = \frac{-1}{3}, x_2 + 2.5x_4 = 0.5, x_3 + \frac{4x_4}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: "line addition": what on earth is that?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I just added the lines with the same variables in the systems ...

Comment: What is the rank of your new system?

Comment: The coefficients of the actual inverse do satisfy your new system, so what's the problem?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I think 3 because the last line is 0

Comment: ou I think I considered the wrong roots in the system last

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $x_1 - \frac{10x_4}{3} = \frac{-1}{3}, x_2 + 2.5x_4 = 0.5, x_3 + \frac{4x_4}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$  I think this is should be correct now... 

But how can I get the inverse matrix of these roots?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Or does this mean that there are many inverse matrices?

Comment: I see what your problem is now: you abandoned the task of solving for $A^{-1}$ in favour of solving the system $B\pmatrix{3\\4}=\pmatrix{1\\1}$ and $\pmatrix{2&5}B=\pmatrix{1&1}$ instead. You found that while $B=A^{-1}$ is a solution to the new system, that it is not the only one.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknownI am not sure that I can understand this answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is even easier that what you have done. Consider $$A^{-1}\cdot A=\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3 & x_4\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

You get your system: \begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   x_1 + 2x_3 = 1, 
   \\
  x_2 + 2x_4 = 0,
   \\
  x_1 + 3 x_3 = 0,
   \\
  x_2 + 3x_4 = 1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Solve it, it is easy to see: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(3,-2,-1,1)$.

You can do the same in the other way. Consider $$A\cdot A^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3 & x_4\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

You get your system: \begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   x_1 + x_2 = 1, 
   \\
  2x_1 + 3x_2 = 0,
   \\
  x_3 + x_4 = 0,
   \\
  2 x_3 + 3x_4 = 1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Solve it, it is easy to see: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(3,-2,-1,1)$.

Hence $$A^{-1}= \left[\begin{matrix}3 & -2\\-1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

Your problem comes when adding these two systems. If you have your new system:

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   x_1 + 2x_3 = 1, 
   \\
  x_2 + 2x_4 = 0,
   \\
  x_1 + 3 x_3 = 0,
   \\
  x_2 + 3x_4 = 1
\\
x_1 + x_2 = 1, 
   \\
  2x_1 + 3x_2 = 0,
   \\
  x_3 + x_4 = 0,
   \\
  2 x_3 + 3x_4 = 1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I think that you have done some bad addition between these equations. Because it should lead the same answer as you have seen above.

Comment: Yes, I have already figured out, thanks)